# Align control on the right in grid

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a grid with 3 columns:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
 <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I want to have the last column align on the right, near to edge of screen.
Currently, the third column occurs soon after the second. I don't want to pass width in pixels, rather automatic calculation.

I have tried to use on the element in third column property HorizontalAlignment="Right", but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Does your Grid itself span the whole screen?

Comment: Yes, it's span for whole container

Comment: I do not understand your question, so what of you code does not work like expected? Can you post a screenshot that shows how it looks and a second image that show how it should looks?

Answer (score 1):

If your Grid is inside of a Stackpanel , no matter what you do it'll only resize iteself to the width of Stackpanel.

If your last column definitions is Auto , you can't align it to the right of the screen.Change 2nd definition to Auto and the last one to *.

Comment: And also if your Grid is inside of a DataTemplate , the control that uses this template has to be set it's HorizontalContentAlignment to stretch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same type of controls inside the grid, you can assign a style for all of them in `<Grid.Resources>`, with setting the HorizontalAlignment property only if the Grid.Column property's value is 2 (with triggers).
But it is even easier for looping through all the children, and checking the column property of each and then setting the alignment, like

```
foreach (Control ctrl in yourGrid.Children) {
    if(Grid.GetColumn(ctrl) == 2) ctrl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your last column has `Auto` width, setting `HorizontalAlignement` of the content to `Right` should not be necessary. My guess would be either

1. your `Grid` doesn't have a `HorizontalAlignement` value of `Stretch` (which should be default), or
2. whatever contains the `Grid` (a `StackPanel` maybe?) is not giving it the full width.

I could be sure if I could check the rest of the XAML. Check these two things first. If these don't help, please post the rest of your XAML.